# Is there a philosophical agreement that the universe is deterministic?

Tags: metaphysics

Is there a philosophical agreement that the universe is deterministic? If the universe is not deterministic, then how come every law in the universe seems to be deterministic? What are the possible implications that can be derived in an universe that is not deterministic? Do some of the rules have to non-deterministic in order for the universe to be considered non-deterministic?

Comment: How do all laws seem deterministic, and how strong/valid is the feeling that there are "laws" at all? But no, philosophy is not a matter of consensus on things. We don't hold secret council with the Childlike Empress in the Ivory Tower, deciding what the public ought to be taught of metaphysics as such.

Comment: No, there is no consensus. A law can not be deterministic or not, determinism means that the totality of laws uniquely determine the future rather than leave open multiple options. Quantum physics is considered indeterministic according to the majority view (Copenhagen interpretation). We are living the implications, presumably. Determinism or lack thereof is empirically undetectable, so we will never know.

Comment: Epicureans (Lucretius' De rerum natura), speculate that the atoms of the body can change their paths according to the will of the mind corresponding to that body. Indeterminism allows the possibility of different paths and the will chooses among them. In the contemporary quantum version, the human will governs the body by means of the presynaptic membranes or the microtubules in the neurons. The synaptic connections are controlled by the mind and the system of neurons is controlled  by  the  synaptic  connection https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0208104

Comment: I think indeterminism of universe is related to what you think about "Free Will" ? Conway and Kochen, defined something to be “free” when its actions are not explicitly determined by the past, and then proved the “Free Will Theorem” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_theorem and https://www.askamathematician.com/2018/11/q-can-free-will-exist-in-our-deterministic-universe/

Comment: Vaidman argue that the quantum theory of the wave function of the Universe is a very successful deterministic theory fully consistent with our experimental evidence. However, it requires accepting that the world we experience is only part of the reality and there are numerous parallel worlds. The existence of parallel worlds allows us to have a clear deterministic and local physical theory.https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40509-014-0008-4

Comment: The philosophy of determinism claims that all events in the universe are determined by preexisting causes, including moral choices. This means that there’s a cause-and-effect relation between all events in the universe. It also means that human free will doesn’t actually exist.https://www.thegreatcoursesdaily.com/quantum-universe-fundamentally-probabilistic-not-deterministic/#:~:text=The%20philosophy%20of%20determinism%20claims,will%20doesn't%20actually%20exist.

Comment: @hades may you edit the question which type of indeterminism you mean? Subjective indeterminism or objective indeterminism ? . But another approach is by the point of view of Anthropic Principle and Indeterminism. https://www.quora.com/Is-the-universe-deterministic-3

Comment: Can not begin to imagine what linkage can be demonstrated between human experience and quantum physics. Unless someone views themself as some sort of 'bundle' of disassociated atoms. Please tell me you are not that confused.